# Select the sum of occurances of first alphabetical character

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Hi what i need to do is create a select statement which outputs the sum of the first character in a field within the table so the output would look something like

```
A,12
B,0
C,20
D,14
E,0
ect...
```

The table is called contacts, in the above there was 12 occurrences of people whose names begin with the letter A

I hope i have explained this correctly

Comment: Assuming ASCII character set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's understand this with EMP table example.

```
SQL> with
  2      letters
  3      as
  4      (select chr( ascii('A')+level-1 ) letter
  5         from dual
  6      connect by level <= 26
  7      )
  8  SELECT substr(ename, 1, 1) AS init_name,
  9  count(*) cnt
 10  FROM emp
 11  WHERE substr(ename, 1, 1) IN (SELECT letter from letters)
 12  GROUP BY substr(ename, 1, 1)
 13  UNION
 14  SELECT l.letter AS init_name,
 15  0 cnt
 16  FROM letters l
 17  WHERE l.letter NOT IN (SELECT substr(ename, 1, 1) FROM emp)
 18  ORDER BY init_name
 19  /

I        CNT
- ----------
A          2
B          1
C          1
D          0
E          0
F          1
G          0
H          0
I          0
J          2
K          1
L          0
M          2
N          0
O          0
P          0
Q          0
R          0
S          2
T          1
U          0
V          0
W          1
X          0
Y          0
Z          0

26 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So, it gives the `count` of each letter of first name, and for the other letters which **does not exist** in the first name, the count is `0`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works for ASCII character set.

Answer (score 1):

Generate the 26 letters using `connect` then left join to the first letter of the name and count them:

```
select letter, count(name) count
from (select chr(ascii('A')+level-1) letter from dual connect by level < 27) l
left join emp on substr(name, 1, 1) = letter
group by letter order by 1
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d459/3)

<sub>Attribution: My technique of generating letters uses elements of [Lalit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26624304/256196).</sub>

Comment: Will this work when there is no name for the given alpahabet?
It wont print 0 in those cases

Comment: @arunb2w, this will show only those alphabets which exist in the table. If you want the other alphabets too, then check my answer.

Comment: @lalit yes, I missed that point. But your answer can be better done with a join and no union if you join letters left join the substr.

Comment: `left outer join` would keep all the non-matching alphabets as a single count due to the group by.

Comment: @lalit no, you're wrong about that. See my edited answer that achieves the solution with a left join and you can follow the link to see it in action working correctly.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood you initially. Got it now.

Comment: @LalitKumarB The "trick" was to use `count(name)`, which works because `count()` ignores nulls and left joined rows have null columns. Had I coded `count(*)`, which counts *rows*, the count for missing letters would have been `1` (which was your concern). But I learned a neat way of generating a series in oracle, so thanks for that :)