# Oracle : Count entity created last 12 month

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm looking for a way to get the number of entity created the last 12 month. I tried something, but i have 2 issues :

- i have only the 12 month of the current year
- my query returns null if no entity is created during a month.

My sql :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM users 
WHERE extract(year FROM signin_date) = ? 
GROUP BY extract(month FROM signin_date)
```

Is there any way in sql to get something like that ?

```
| COUNT |
| 0     |      (january 2014)
| 3     |      (february 2014)
| 0     |      (march 2014)
...
```

I also found that : [SQL select multiple counts in the last 12 months including missing months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205285/sql-select-multiple-counts-in-the-last-12-months-including-missing-months)
but i don't really understand how to adapt it for my problem.

Comment: Don't use `count(*)`, use `count(column_name)`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, what I meant is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623733/select-the-sum-of-occurances-of-first-alphabetical-character

Comment: @LalitKumarB, why do you suggest not using `COUNT(*)`? It seems reasonable in this instance.

Comment: My concern is exactly related to the link I have posted above, where I have answered to a similar question. Since `count(*)` would ignore NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to include a zero count for months where there is no row in the table. For this you first need to create a list of possible months and then use an outer join.

```
with month_numbers as (
  select level as month
  from dual
  connect by level <= 12
), this_year_users as (
  select id, extract(month FROM u.signin_date) as signin_month
  from users
  where extract(year FROM signin_date) = ? 
)
select mn.month, count(u.id) 
from month_numbers mn
  left join this_year_users u on u.signin_month = mn.month
group by mn.month;
```

The first common table expression is a trick to generate a list of consecutive number against which you can later join.

The second common table expression simply selects all users from this month. And the final select then does an outer join between "all months" and the filtered user table, counting the number of users for each month. The query assumes that there is a non-nullable column named `id` in the `users` table (e.g. the primary key).

---

If you want the "last 12 months" you need a different list of possible "dates" which does not only include the month number but also the year to deal with intervals that go back to the previous year:

```
with month_numbers as (
  select to_char(add_months(trunc(current_date), -level), 'yyyy-mm') as month
  from dual
  connect by level <= 12
)
select mn.month, count(u.signin_date) 
from month_numbers mn
  left join users u on to_char(u.signin_date, 'yyyy-mm') = mn.month
group by mn.month
order by mn.month;
```

This won't include the "current month", if you want that, just replace `-level` with `-(level - 1)` in the `month_numbers` CTE.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e02ac/2

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM users 
WHERE signin_date > add_months(CURRENT_DATE, -12)
GROUP BY extract(month FROM signin_date)
```